# Inequality $|a\ \sin\ x + b\ \cos\ y|<1/9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

Prove that for any real numbers $x$ and $y$, there is two integers $a$ and $b$, not both $0$, with $\lvert a\rvert, \lvert b \rvert \leq 18$ such $$\lvert a\sin\ x + b\cos
\ y\rvert\lt\frac19$$

I try to use the fact that the maximum for the $a\ \sin\ x + b\ \cos\ x $ its $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ but it doesn’t lead me anywhere to conclude something about a and b.

Comment: $ x=y=\pi/2 $ gives $ | a | < 1/9 $. For an integer this implies $ a = 0 $. If you allow $a,b$ to be zero, what you want is trivial ($a=b=0$). If not it doesn't always hold. Are $x$ and $y$ related? (if they aren't this has nothing to do with trigonometry)

Comment: @shortmanikos x and y are not related and a,b aren t both 0

Comment: @ChristianBlatter ok and how i find a and b? Should I use triangle identity?

Answer (score 3):

We are given two numbers $\xi:=\sin x$,  $\>\eta:=\cos y$, both of absolute value $\leq1$, and have to make $|a\xi+b\eta|<{1\over9}$ with integer $a$, $b$ of absolute value $\leq18$.

Consider the symmetric convex set
$$Q:=\left\{(a,b)\in{\mathbb R}^2\biggm| |a|\leq18, \ |b|\leq 18,\ -{1\over9}\leq \xi\,a+\eta\,b\leq 1/9\right\}$$
in the $(a,b)$-plane, and estimate its area. If ${\rm area}(Q)\geq4$ then [Minkowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem) guarantees an integer point $(a,b)\in Q$ different from the origin.

For the estimate we may assume $(\xi,\eta)\ne(0,0)$. The two lines $\xi\,a+\eta\,b=\pm 1/9$ then have a distance
$${1\over 9\sqrt{\xi^2+\eta^2}}\geq{1\over9\sqrt{2}}=:\rho<0.08$$
from the origin. Parallels at  distance $\rho$ intersect the circle with radius $18$ in four points. The rectangle $R\subset Q$ with these points as vertices has an area slightly smaller than $36\cdot2\rho=4\sqrt{2}$.