# Existence of $e$ such that there exist integers $x,y$ not both $0$ and that $\left|ax^2 + bxy + cy^2\right|\le e\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, geometry-of-numbers

Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers with $a > 0$. Suppose that $d = b^2 - 4ac > 0$. Is there a constant $e$ such that there exist integers $x,y$ not both $0$ and that $\left|ax^2 + bxy + cy^2\right|\le e\sqrt d$ ?

That question is a modified form of Problem 12 in Section 6.4, "The Geometry of Numbers," in I. Niven, H. S. Zuckerman, H. L. Montgomery, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* 5th ed., Wiley (New York), 1991.

The [solution to Problem 12](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027014#2243732) was relatively easy because the region is that of an ellipse, which is convex and has an easy-to-calculate area, so all we had to do was use a [modified version of Minkowski's convex body theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90158).

The region of the question posed above, however, is not convex and has a weird shape; part of its boundary is hyperbolic.

Comment: My comment is inspired by the following :

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3675922/inequality-a-sin-x-b-cos-y1-9


This problem is equivalent to the following :

 Consider a region $R$ which is enclosed by two hyperbolas s.t. they share
 same asymptotes $l_i$ (Here $l_i$ is in $R$)

 Here $R$ contains a rectangle $G$ whose center is origin s.t. four vertices in
 hyperbolas are mid points of sides in $G$. Then is there a constant i.e. area of
 $G$ s.t. $R$ contains $(x,y)$, not origin, where $x,\ y$ are integers.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
f(x, y)
&=ax^2+bxy+cy^2\\
&=ay^2((x/y)^2+(b/a)(x/y)+(c/a))\\
&=ay^2((x/y)-r)((x/y)-s)\\
\end{array}
$

where $r$ and $s$
are the roots of
$x^2+(b/a)x+(c/a)
=0$.

These roots are

$\begin{array}\\
r, s
&=\dfrac{-b/a\pm\sqrt{b^2/a^2-4c/a}}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\\
&=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{d}}{2a}\\
&= u \pm v
\qquad\text{where } u = -\dfrac{b}{2a}, v = \dfrac{\sqrt{d}}{2a}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$d > 0$,
$r$ and $s$ are real.

Therefore
$f(x, y)
=ax^2+bxy+cy^2
=ay^2((x/y)-r)((x/y)-s)
=a(x-ry)(x-sy)
$.
So we want
$|a(x-ry)(x-sy)|
\le e\sqrt{d}
$.

Choosing
$r
= u+v
$
and
$s
= u-v
$,

$\begin{array}\\
a(x-ry)(x-sy)
&=a(x-(u+v)y)(x-(u-v)y)\\
&=a(x-uy-vy)(x-uy+vy)\\
&=a((x-uy)^2-(vy)^2)\\
\end{array}
$

so we want
$e\sqrt{d}
\ge a|(x-uy)^2-(vy)^2|
$.

For any integer $y$,
we can choose an integer $x$
such that
$|x-uy| \lt 1$.

If $|y| = 1$
then
$|(x-uy)^2-(vy)^2|
\lt 1+v^2
$
so 
$e\sqrt{d}
\ge a(1+v^2)
$
will certainly do.

This is
$e\sqrt{d}
\ge a(1+\frac{d}{4a^2})
$
or
$e 
\ge  \dfrac{a}{\sqrt{d}}(1+\dfrac{d}{4a^2})
=  \dfrac{a}{\sqrt{d}}+\dfrac{\sqrt{d}}{4a}
$.

Comment: I had in mind that $e$ does not depend on $a,b,c$. For example, in the original [Problem 12](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027014) where $d < 0$, $e = 2/\pi$. (If we are allowed to let $e$ depend on $a,b,c$, we can simply choose an $x,y$ and solve for $e$. For instance, choose $x = 1 = y$. Then any $e$ greater than $|a + b + c|/\sqrt d$ would do.)